# Comparing Cloud Functions for Firebase database triggers onCreate(), onWrite(), onUpdate(), when to use?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

It's a simple question, I have seen all these methods addressed in the title in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) but all the examples are using onWrite() for triggering database events which then one would have to check to make sure it's not for removing or updating with

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onWrite(event => {
...
  // Only edit data when it is first created.
      if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
        return;
      }
      // Exit when the data is deleted.
      if (!event.data.exists()) {
        return;
      }
...
});
```

The only examples with onCreate() for instance, are related to auth events. Is there a reason or am I just being paranoid? Why not just use onCreate() and not bother the check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onCreate()`, `onUpdate()` and `onDelete()` were added in the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions (v0.5.9) release on 7 July 2017.  This is detailed in [the release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases):

> An updated beta release of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions
>   (v0.5.9) is now available. It includes the ability to listen to
>   granular create, update, and delete database events by using the
>   onCreate(), onUpdate(), and onDelete() methods.

Prior to that release, the only database event handler was `onWrite()`.  The documentation has not yet been updated to include examples of the new handlers.

There is no reason not to take advantage of the convenience of the new handlers.

Comment: thxx @Bob. was wondering how come my push is being triggered when im just updating the post. cuz i was using onWrite() method.